# NSUrlSession dataTask Completion handler parameters

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

What is the difference between the data and response parameters in the dataTask method's completion handler? Which one is used for what? Which one is the one where the json data will be returned by the web api?

Answer (score 0):

JSON data is returned in the `data` parameter. The `response` parameter is a [URLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlresponse) object. You can use it to access additional information about the response (also known as metadata), such as its MIME type. If your request was an HTTP request `response` will be an [HTTPURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse), which will include the HTTP status code and the HTTP header fields sent back by the server.

Comment: if there is no response from the server, is the field nil?

Comment: I believe that's the case. The documentation states: "If a response from the server is received, regardless of whether the request completes successfully or fails, the response parameter contains that information." But if no response is received, there's nothing to put in the response parameter. The error parameter will be non-nil, and indicate that there was no response.